# Is there any software to auto-generate diagram for the whole source code repository/folder

Tags: open-source, software-development, diagram, filesystems

I'm working with the source code. I want to have an overview of the whole source code faster, something like the connections, relationship, data sent between the folders/files. Is there any tool/software that I can put the whole work folder in and let it run then generates a diagram with descriptions of things above or a profiler that outputs something like for example: file1.py imports *something* from folder2/file2.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking for an inexpensive dependency graph generator as well, but for C++.  In my searching I did find a reference to something that might help you if you haven't already found a solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49647897/11035837